# How to trigger a function in a Python REST API

Tags: python, rest, flask, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a local Flask REST API that runs some queries and return JSON responses. My idea is to send a POST request to the API and trigger a function capable of updating my database.

The inspiration behind this idea is the way we create resources in a public Cloud. Example: let's say we create a Virtual Cloud Network on any public cloud. The cloud architecture has several APIs for each module and the creation of a VCN trigger the creation of NAT Gateways, Route Tables, Security Lists, Subnets and so on through a GET or POST request to each resource type.

So inspired by this architecture, I want to do this in a simplified and local manner. My first guess is to use the multiprocessing library to spawn processes as soon as a request hits the endpoint, but I don't know if this the best way or a good practice. Can anyone give me an idea on how to do this or if I am in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

i dont really understand... but i can try to help you,
the following code is a code that is the same API but you can get different responses, i dont know what are you going to do with so i added my own examples.

```py
from flask import *
app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/api/route/1', methods=['POST'])
def api_1():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Some code here 
        #Eg:
        # data = request.get_json()
        # print(data)
        #return data.thing

        #OR

        return "Hello from route 1"

@app.route('/api/route/2', methods=['POST'])
def api_2():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Some code here 
        #Eg:
        # data = request.get_json()
        # print(data)
        #return data.thing

        #OR

        return "Hello from route 2"
@app.route('/api/route/3', methods=['POST'])
def api_3():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Some code here 
        #Eg:
        # data = request.get_json()
        # print(data)
        #return data.thing

        #OR

        return "Hello from route 3"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, debug=True)
```

Comment: Yes, this is the basics of a REST API in Flask. What I want is to know what is the best practice to spawn processes when some requests hits some endpoints, inspired by the way the Cloud create several resources with just the click of a button.